# Bootstrap 5.2 Carousel wo'nt show the third image

Tags: html, css, shopify, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to have a 3 page carousel that displays my products image and callouts but somehow it's only showing only 2 images it wont go to the third one.

In the `{% render 'meliades' %}` part I'm only including the image and callout from different page everything is the same except call out position and images.

```css
.BornHS__Wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Close {
  display: none;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .Content__Wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content {
  background: #2b2b2bcc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  color: #2b2b2b;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 4;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .Content__Wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .Content__Wrapper .BornHS__Title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .Content__Wrapper p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input+.BornHS__Label {
  background: #f4f4f480;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px !important;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  width: 20px !important;
  z-index: 2;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input+.BornHS__Label:before,
.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input+.BornHS__Label:after {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input+.BornHS__Label:before {
  height: 2px;
  width: 40%;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input+.BornHS__Label:after {
  height: 40%;
  width: 2px;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input~.BornHS__Overlay {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input:checked+.BornHS__Label {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input:checked~.BornHS__Modal__Content {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Input:checked~.BornHS__Overlay {
  display: block;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper.BornHS__Blur figure {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.BornHS__Wrapper.BornHS__Blur .BornHS__Input {
  display: none;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper.BornHS__Blur .BornHS__Input+.BornHS__Label {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper.BornHS__Blur .BornHS__Input:checked {
  display: inline-block;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper.BornHS__Blur .BornHS__Input:checked+.BornHS__Label {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.BornHS__Modal {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .BornHS__Close {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  right: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .BornHS__Close:before,
.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .BornHS__Close:after {
  background: #fff;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .BornHS__Close:before {
  height: 2px;
  width: 40%;
}

.BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .BornHS__Close:after {
  height: 40%;
  width: 2px;
}


/* START - 428 - START */

@media (max-width: 428px) {
  .BornHS__Wrapper .BornHS__Modal__Content .Content__Wrapper .BornHS__Title {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .callOutProductTitle {
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
  .callOutProductSKU {
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }
  .callOutProductPage {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    color: #9b8642 !important;
  }
  #meliades-circle-1 {
    left: 67%;
    top: 37%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-2 {
    left: 80%;
    top: 40%;
    display: none;
  }
  #meliades-circle-3 {
    left: 30%;
    top: 48%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-4 {
    left: 47.5%;
    top: 60%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-5 {
    left: 55%;
    top: 46.5%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-6 {
    left: 93%;
    top: 21.5%;
  }
  #meliades-content-1 {
    left: 7%;
    top: 26%;
  }
  #meliades-content-2 {
    left: 20%;
    top: 47%;
  }
  #meliades-content-3 {
    left: 6%;
    top: 37%;
  }
  #meliades-content-4 {
    left: 13%;
    top: 68%;
  }
  #meliades-content-5 {
    left: 57%;
    top: 55%;
  }
  #meliades-content-6 {
    left: 47.5%;
    top: 11%;
  }
}


/* END - 428 - END */


/* START - 768 - START */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #meliades-circle-1 {
    left: 71%;
    top: 37%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-2 {
    left: 80%;
    top: 40%;
    display: none;
  }
  #meliades-circle-3 {
    left: 29%;
    top: 49%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-4 {
    left: 48%;
    top: 60%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-5 {
    left: 55%;
    top: 49%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-6 {
    left: 95%;
    top: 22.5%;
  }
  #meliades-content-1 {
    left: 18%;
    top: 30%;
  }
  #meliades-content-2 {
    left: 20%;
    top: 47%;
  }
  #meliades-content-3 {
    left: 11.5%;
    top: 43%;
  }
  #meliades-content-4 {
    left: 22.5%;
    top: 64%;
  }
  #meliades-content-5 {
    left: 56%;
    top: 53%;
  }
  #meliades-content-6 {
    left: 64.5%;
    top: 16%;
  }
}


/* END - 768 - END */


/* START - 1024 - START */

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #meliades-circle-1 {
    left: 71%;
    top: 37%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-2 {
    left: 80%;
    top: 40%;
    display: none;
  }
  #meliades-circle-3 {
    left: 30%;
    top: 49%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-4 {
    left: 49%;
    top: 60%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-5 {
    left: 57%;
    top: 48%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-6 {
    left: 95%;
    top: 23%;
  }
  #meliades-content-1 {
    left: 31.5%;
    top: 32%;
  }
  #meliades-content-2 {
    left: 82%;
    top: 45%;
  }
  #meliades-content-3 {
    left: 17%;
    top: 44%;
  }
  #meliades-content-4 {
    left: 50%;
    top: 63%;
  }
  #meliades-content-5 {
    left: 58%;
    top: 51%;
  }
  #meliades-content-6 {
    left: 72%;
    top: 18%;
  }
}


/* END - 1024 - END */


/* START - 1280 - START */

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  #meliades-circle-1 {
    left: 58%;
    top: 39%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-2 {
    left: 80%;
    top: 40%;
    display: none;
  }
  #meliades-circle-3 {
    left: 40%;
    top: 49%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-4 {
    left: 49.2%;
    top: 60%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-5 {
    left: 55%;
    top: 45.5%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-6 {
    left: 72%;
    top: 22.5%;
  }
  #meliades-content-1 {
    left: 58.8%;
    top: 44%;
  }
  #meliades-content-2 {
    left: 20%;
    top: 47%;
  }
  #meliades-content-3 {
    left: 29.5%;
    top: 40%;
  }
  #meliades-content-4 {
    left: 49.8%;
    top: 65%;
  }
  #meliades-content-5 {
    left: 55.5%;
    top: 51%;
  }
  #meliades-content-6 {
    left: 72.7%;
    top: 14%;
  }
}


/* END - 1280 - END */


/* START - 1366 - START */

@media (min-width: 1366px) {
  #meliades-circle-1 {
    left: 58.1%;
    top: 38%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-2 {
    left: 80%;
    top: 40%;
    display: none;
  }
  #meliades-circle-3 {
    left: 40%;
    top: 49%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-4 {
    left: 49.3%;
    top: 60%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-5 {
    left: 55%;
    top: 46%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-6 {
    left: 72%;
    top: 22.5%;
  }
  #meliades-content-1 {
    left: 58.6%;
    top: 43%;
  }
  #meliades-content-2 {
    left: 20%;
    top: 47%;
  }
  #meliades-content-3 {
    left: 30.2%;
    top: 41%;
  }
  #meliades-content-4 {
    left: 49.8%;
    top: 65%;
  }
  #meliades-content-5 {
    left: 55.7%;
    top: 51%;
  }
  #meliades-content-6 {
    left: 72.7%;
    top: 15%;
  }
}


/* END - 1366 - END */


/* START - 1440 - START */

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  .imageSize {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-1 {
    left: 60%;
    top: 37%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-2 {
    left: 80%;
    top: 40%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-3 {
    left: 40%;
    top: 49%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-4 {
    left: 49.2%;
    top: 60%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-5 {
    left: 55.5%;
    top: 45%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-6 {
    left: 72.5%;
    top: 22.5%;
  }
  #meliades-content-1 {
    left: 60.5%;
    top: 41%;
  }
  #meliades-content-2 {
    left: 82%;
    top: 45%;
  }
  #meliades-content-3 {
    left: 30.5%;
    top: 42%;
  }
  #meliades-content-4 {
    left: 49.5%;
    top: 64%;
  }
  #meliades-content-5 {
    left: 56%;
    top: 49%;
  }
  #meliades-content-6 {
    left: 73.2%;
    top: 15%;
  }
}


/* END - 1440 - END */


/* START - 1920 - START */

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #meliades-circle-1 {
    left: 57%;
    top: 40.5%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-2 {
    left: 76%;
    top: 40%;
    display: none;
  }
  #meliades-circle-3 {
    left: 40%;
    top: 50%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-4 {
    left: 49.5%;
    top: 60%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-5 {
    left: 55%;
    top: 46.5%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-6 {
    left: 73%;
    top: 22.5%;
  }
  #meliades-content-1 {
    left: 57.5%;
    top: 44%;
  }
  #meliades-content-2 {
    right: -20%;
    top: 45%;
  }
  #meliades-content-3 {
    left: 33%;
    top: 44%;
  }
  #meliades-content-4 {
    left: 50%;
    top: 64%;
  }
  #meliades-content-5 {
    left: 55.5%;
    top: 50%;
  }
  #meliades-content-6 {
    left: 73.5%;
    top: 17%;
  }
}


/* END - 1920 - END */


/* START - 2560 - START */

@media (min-width: 2560px) {
  #meliades-circle-1 {
    left: 60.5%;
    top: 37%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-2 {
    left: 80%;
    top: 40%;
    display: none;
  }
  #meliades-circle-3 {
    left: 40%;
    top: 49%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-4 {
    left: 49.5%;
    top: 60%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-5 {
    left: 55%;
    top: 47%;
  }
  #meliades-circle-6 {
    left: 73%;
    top: 23%;
  }
  #meliades-content-1 {
    left: 60.8%;
    top: 40%;
  }
  #meliades-content-2 {
    left: 20%;
    top: 47%;
  }
  #meliades-content-3 {
    left: 34.8%;
    top: 45%;
  }
  #meliades-content-4 {
    left: 49.8%;
    top: 62.5%;
  }
  #meliades-content-5 {
    left: 55.4%;
    top: 49.5%;
  }
  #meliades-content-6 {
    left: 73.4%;
    top: 19%;
  }
}


/* END - 2560 - END */

@-webkit-keyframes sonar {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #f4f4f4, 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 147, 223, 0), 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
}

@keyframes sonar {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #f4f4f4, 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 147, 223, 0), 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
}

.sonar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
  -webkit-animation: sonar 1300ms ease-out infinite;
  animation: sonar 1300ms ease-out infinite;
}

.callOutProductTitle {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.callOutProductSKU {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.callOutProductPage {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9b8642 !important;
}

.callOutProductPage:hover {
  color: #9b8642 !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.callOutDiv {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      {% render 'meliades' %}
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      {% render 'white-matera' %}
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      {% render 'mezuzah' %}
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Is all that CSS relevant here? Please revise to simplify. Also, show us rendered HTML, not your backend code.

Comment: render html is included at the very top for "meliades" with the css the other renders are including the same codes just a different css positioning of a image.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. The demo _doesn't work_ because it's missing HTML. Please fix that so we can help. This is apparently a Bootstrap issue, so let's see what the Bootstrap library sees in the browser.

Comment: Correction: The demo works fine, but it doesn't show your problem. Therefore, we can't really help. Show us the actual scenario, please.